# Maximum Supremum and Minimum Infimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Find the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of the following set
$$A = \left\{x = \dfrac{n^2}{n+2},\; n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$
Is the $\sup$ a maximum for $A$? Is the $\inf$ a minimum for $A$?

Comment: Have you tried to see whether $A$ is bounded from above or below? It will help if you include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to MSE, please know that this isn’t a do-my-homework site, and as such you need to show what you have done, and all the steps you have taken to attempt to solve this problem. For more information, please look to here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Yep. Sup is the maximum value in $A$ and inf the minimum. It will probably be helpful to consider the function $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x+2}$$ and noting that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.